# Why is Gnome 3.14 window decoration inconsistent

Tags: debian, gnome3, gtk, window-decorations

[image: Screenshot]

I am using debian testing with gnome 3.14. despite trying googling around why that happened, I  didn't find a solution.

My question is:
Why is my terminal and sublime text not consistent with the gtk theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem ! Here is the solution, move the themes from home/.themes to /usr/share/themes. The problem was that apparently meta-city themes were not recognized there. Once I moved them to the folder everything got resolved.
Hope that helps someone like me !